# How can I access to the guild IDs (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("STARTTTTTTT");

    const guildId = // ??
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
    let commands

    if (guild) {
        commands = guild.commands
    } else {
        commands = client.application?.commands
    }

    commands?.create({
        name: "lena",
        description: "LENAAAAAAAAAA",
        options: [
            {
                name: 'name',
                description: "LENAAAAAAA",
                required: true,
                type: Discord.Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.STRING
            },
            {
                name: 'text',
                description: "LENAAA",
                required: false,
                type: Discord.Constants.ApplicationCommandOptionTypes.STRING
            },
        ]
    })
})
```

In line 4 you can see that I need to define on Guild Ids, the question I am asking myself is how do I access all of them, how do I access all the servers that my discord bot is on?

Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: `client.guilds.cache` returns a Collection<id, guild> of all the cached guilds your bot is in. [Learn About Collections Here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `client.guilds.cache`

```js
console.log(client.guilds.cache) // Collection of all guild objects
```

To get it as an array:

```js
console.log([...client.guilds.cache.values()])
```

To get all IDs

```js
console.log(client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.id)) // Array of IDs
```